# how to weight paint a particular part of a mesh?

Tags: rendering

is there a way to weight paint a particular area of a mesh? because in whole it is quite difficult to control the paint . If yes then please suggest. That would be a great help . Thank you

Comment: Hello, it should not be difficult to paint a part of a mesh, maybe your problem is that it is not dense enough, weight paint allows you to assign vertices to vertex groups, so the precision will completely depend on the mesh density

Comment: actually yes it is something like that @moonboots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be difficult to paint a part of a mesh, maybe your problem is that it is not dense enough, weight paint allows you to assign vertices to vertex groups, so the precision will completely depend on the mesh density.

On the left a low-poly plane, on the right a higher-poly plane:

[image]

Comment: thank you @moonboots that was really helpfu